# Catch dll function that does not return

Tags: c++, multithreading, exception, dll, infinite-loop

i do have to use a .dll library in order to have access to hardware i want to control.

The problem is, that some functions of that dll sometimes do not return. They seem to be stuck in an infinite loop or something.

My idea was to run the function calls in a different thread and kill the thread if it is stuck/does not return after some time.
In Order to do that i wrote something like that:

```
template<typename... multiple>
void MyClass::genericCommandHandler(void *function, multiple... args)
{
    //timer start --> check somewhere else
    std::thread t{&MyClass::threadWorker<void(*)(...)>, function, args...};
    t.join();
}
```

But it does not compile: `error C2672: 'std::invoke': no matching overloaded function found`

And another Problem is that std::thread does not have a kill or stop function.

Does anyone have a good idea on how to deal with a dll that does not return?

Comment: AFAIK, In C/C++, a code that never returns is ill formed and running it cause an undefined behaviour (though it often works). Besides this, forcing people to kill a thread is also generally a sign of poorly design code (and killing it too) because this is unsafe (it makes your process unstable and leaky). Are you sure there is no way to stop this properly? If no, please consider asking developers to add this feature (ie. remove this bug).

Comment: @JérômeRichard: Incorrect. There's nothing specific in the C++ standard that would explicitly make such non-returning code UB.  There is a narrower specific form of UB for code that does not return, and additionally does not produce any observable effects either. But printing "Hello, world" every century would already qualify.

Comment: The `std::invoke` is probably because `&MyClass::threadWorker<void(*)(...)>` is a template instantiation using C-style varargs, not the C++ `typename... multiple` .

Comment: @MSalters Indeed for C++, I forgot observable behaviours (more specifically a subset of them defined [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/memory_model)).

Comment: You really need to get to the bottom of those functions in the dll. You should not call functions if you really don't know what's going on. Maybe it's bugs, maybe you called them wrong. Talk to the writers

Comment: @jerome nearly all microcontroller code, Arduino (which is c++) for example, sits in a tight 'forever' loop

Comment: thanks for the answers!
The function i use gives me back an index that tells me what operation is currently in work on the hardware. so i thought i cannot call it in a wrong way, but in fact i did change the way i started the queue and since then the index was always succsessfully returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isolating the DLL in its own thread does not really help a lot, but the idea makes sense. It might be better to isolate the DLL in its own helper process. You would then terminate the entire helper process.

This is by necessity not a clean exit. That is inherent in the problem. You don't know how the DLL corrupted internal state. That is why the helper process exists: to avoid mingling DLL state and your state.

The C++ Standard way to mange subprocesses is `std::system`, but that has the same problem with control. You'll need the native `CreateProcess`.

As a shotgun method, you could try `CancelSynchronousIo` on the DLL's thread.

Comment: yes, making a new process is probably the only way to handle a stuck dll.